# iPhoneAppでバックグランドで常時実行する方法はありませんか？

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

バックグランドで実行させたいiPhoneアプリを作っているのですが、方法がよく分かりません。
考えているアプリの動作方法としては、

１.一度そのアプリを起動させ、一旦閉じる

２.画面がホーム画面や他のアプリを起動している時に、バックグラウンドで加速度センサーとジャイロセンサー 　を使ってデバイスの揺れ、傾きを検出する。

３.検出した値に条件を絞ってバナーに通知を出す（LINEの通知のような感じで）。

以上の方法を教えてください。

Comment: [iOSアプリケーションプログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf)の「長時間動作するタスクを実装する」は読まれましたでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

フォアグラウンドで問題無く動作しているのであれば、info.Plistの設定の問題と思います。

`info.plist` -> `Required background modes`(＋から追加)

追記
②について
認識不足でしたがCoreMotionのみではbackgroundでの傾き等へ検出出来ないようです。
ですので、CoreLocationと組み合わせて実装することで、動作することを確認しました。
iOS8でテストしましたので、info.plistで`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`の追加も必要です。
swiftですが、codeを記載します。
環境
Xcode6.1.1
iOS8.1
iPhone6

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    var myMotionManager: CMMotionManager!
    var locManager: CLLocationManager?

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locManager = CLLocationManager();
        self.locManager!.delegate = self;
        if (!CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
            println("Location services are not enabled");
        }
        self.locManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization();
        self.locManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false;
        self.locManager!.startUpdatingLocation()

        // MotionManagerを生成.
        myMotionManager = CMMotionManager()

        // 更新周期を設定.
        myMotionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.5

        // 加速度の取得を開始.
        myMotionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), withHandler: {(accelerometerData:CMAccelerometerData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            println(accelerometerData.acceleration.x)
        })

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
        //println(newLocation.timestamp)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[参考 独立型戦闘支援ブログ様](http://tanakahiroki.com/?p=371)

Comment: フォアグラウンドでは問題なく動いています。
info.plistでは具体的に何を追加すればいいのですか？
このAppでは位置情報も使うのでApp registers for location updatesは追加してあります。